# Monit Password Restrictions?

Tags: terminal, monit

Are there password requirements for a monit password?

I'm unable to start monit. Doing monit -t shows that the syntax error is a ! In my password. I changed it to % and then it said that character was the problem.

Where do I find what symbols are acceptable? Or does the password need quotes around it or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show your monit config... You may be able to use quotes.

Is your password set with:

```
  set httpd port 2812
      allow localhost
      allow 10.1.1.1
      allow user1:"password"
```

Comment: Passoword has no quotes as of yet. Simple allow user1:password as suggested by media temple: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv)_4.0_-_Making_It_Better_::_Installing_Monit

Comment: Per my last link by media temple on how to setup, my config can be seen here: http://pastie.org/5031846

Comment: Monit support got back and agreed that I need quotes. Thanks!